# Получение индекса элемента массива, который встречается чаще всего

Tags: java

Мне нужно вывести индекс второго с конца элемента, который встречается в массиве чаще всего.

Например, есть массив [100 76 84 66 66 122 76 443 9 12 66 12]. Здесь чаще всего встречается число 66. У него индексы 3, 4 и 10. Нужно, чтобы программа вывела 4(второй индекс с конца). Если несколько значений встречаются в массиве одинаковое количество раз, то нужно выбрать наибольшее по модулю значение, а потом просто наибольшее значение.

У меня есть код, но он работает не совсем правильно, вернее совсем не работает:

```
   public static int absMaxFrequentNumber(int[] array) {

        int maxCount = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int maxNumber = array[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j  = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] == array[j] && Math.abs(array[i]) >= maxNumber) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count >= maxCount) {
                    maxCount = count;
                    index = i;

                }
            }
        }
        if (maxCount == 1){
            return -1;
        }else {
            return index;
        }
    }

    public static int maxFrequentNumber(int[] array) {

        int maxCount = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int maxNumber = array[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j  = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count >= maxCount && array[i] >= maxNumber) {
                    maxCount = count;
                    index = i;

                }
            }
        }
        if (maxCount == 1){
            return -1;
        }else {
            return index;
        }
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, я новичок в java

Также, при попытке вызвать функции, пишет ошибку:

`Result of 'Main.absMaxFrequentNumber()' is ignored`

`Result of 'Main.maxFrequentNumber()' is ignored`

Comment: is ignored - значит, что выражение игнорируется, т.е. мы что-то сделали, но не записали в переменную или не вывели в консоль. безсмысленное действие.

Comment: "но он работает не совсем правильно, вернее совсем не работает" - I love you, +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Мы можем создать объект типа `Map`, который будет хранить элемент и список индексов этого элемента.
2. При просмотре массива мы добавляем в map пару **число - список с его индексом**, если такого числа не было в map ранее, а если присутствовал, то получаем список для данного числа, и помещаем туда еще один индекс.
3. После ищем максимальный по размеру список среди всех в данном map и сохраняем его индекс.
4. Если таких списков несколько, то выбираем наибольшее по модулю значение.
5. Выводим на экран size() - 2 элемент, так как это предпоследний с конца элемент.

   ```
    int[] array = {100, 76, 84, 66, 66, 122, 76,443, 9, 12, 66, 12};
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(!map.containsKey(array[i])) {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(i);
            map.put(array[i], list);
        } else {
            List<Integer> list = map.get(array[i]);
            list.add(i);
            map.put(array[i], list);
        }
    }
    int maxSize = 0;
    int maxInt = 0;
    for(Integer i : map.keySet()) {
        if(map.get(i).size() > maxSize) {
            maxSize = map.get(i).size();
            maxInt = i;
        } else if(map.get(i).size() == maxSize) {
            if(Math.abs(i) > Math.abs(maxInt)) {
                maxInt = i;
            }
        }
    }
    List<Integer> list = map.get(maxInt);
    System.out.println(list.get(list.size() - 2));
   ```

Суть задач на нахождение повторений - использование колекций Map и Set.

Answer (score 0):

Все хорошо, но слишком много кода, читаемость нулевая и в этом основная проблема. Я бы смотрел в сторону функционалки, сделал примерно так, а потом уже рефакторил (это за вами):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Integer [] arr = {100, 76, 84, 66, 66, 122, 76, 443, 9, 12, 66, 12};        
        Integer number = Arrays.stream(arr)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream().max(Comparator.comparingLong(Entry::getValue)).get().getKey();        
        int[] result = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                .filter(i->number.equals(arr[i]))
                .toArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функциональное решение с использованием Stream API и компараторов, в случае ненахождения нужного элемента возвращается `-1`

- поток индексов группируется по значениям в массиве в карту `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`
- поток элементов карты фильтруется, чтобы исключить элементы, встречающиеся менее 2 раз
- находится требуемый элемент карты при помощи компаратора как `Optional<Map.Entry>`
- используем `Optional::map` + `Optional::orElse` чтобы вернуть нужный результат

```java
public static int secondIndexOfMostFrequent(int ... arr) {
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr) + " -> ");
    return IntStream
        .range(0, arr.length)
        .boxed() // Stream<Integer> индексы в массиве
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> arr[i])) // Map<Integer, List<Integer>>
        .entrySet()
        .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>>> значение=список индексов
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1) // 
        .max(Map.Entry.<Integer, List<Integer>>comparingByValue(
            Comparator.comparingInt(List::size))
            .thenComparingInt(e -> Math.abs(e.getKey()))
            .thenComparingInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
        ) // Optional<Map.Entry>
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue) // Optional<List<Integer>>
        .map(indexes -> indexes.get(indexes.size() - 2)) // Optional<Integer> 2nd index
        .orElse(-1);
}
```

Тесты:

```java
int[][] tests = {
    {},
    {1},
    {2, 2},
    {100, -76, 84, 66, 66, 122, -76, 443, 9, 12, 66, 12, -76},
    {100, -76, 84, 76, 76, 122, -76, 443, 9, 12, 76, 12, -76},
    {100, 76, 84, 65, 63, 122, 75, 443, 9, 12, 66, 1}
};        
for (int[] arr : tests) {
    int secondIndex = secondIndexOfMostFrequent(arr);
                     
    System.out.println("arr[" + secondIndex + "] = " + (secondIndex > -1 ? "" + arr[secondIndex] : "NULL"));
}
```

Результаты:

```
[] -> arr[-1] = NULL
[1] -> arr[-1] = NULL
[2, 2] -> arr[0] = 2
[100, -76, 84, 66, 66, 122, -76, 443, 9, 12, 66, 12, -76] -> arr[6] = -76
[100, -76, 84, 76, 76, 122, -76, 443, 9, 12, 76, 12, -76] -> arr[4] = 76
[100, 76, 84, 65, 63, 122, 75, 443, 9, 12, 66, 1] -> arr[-1] = NULL
```

---

Аналогичное решение без применения Stream API:

```java
static int nonStreamAPI(int ... array) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    int ix = 0;
    for (int x : array) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(x, (k) -> new ArrayList<>()).add(ix++);
    }
    Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> max = null;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> e : map.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue().size() > 1) {
            if (null == max 
                || max.getValue().size() < e.getValue().size() 
                || Math.abs(max.getKey()) < Math.abs(e.getKey()) 
                || Math.abs(max.getKey()) == Math.abs(e.getKey()) 
                && max.getKey() < e.getKey()
            ) {
                max = e;
            }
        }
    }
    return null == max ? -1 : max.getValue().get(max.getValue().size() - 2);
}
```